# What is this tool? It is cast iron and looks like a router attached to an adjustable fence

Tags: hand-tools, identify-a-tool

This antique cast iron tool is apparently for carpenters and incorporates a router section with an adjustable fence.  What is it called and who made it?

[image]

Comment: Picture not coming/bad link.

Comment: looks like you added the picture and then deleted the link to the picture, so the picture isn't added after all. [edit] and try again, and don't delete the gobbledegook it puts at the bottom of the edit box...

Comment: Not sure who did a -1 on a new user with a good question and some technical issues, but welcome aboard and likely a +1 from me and many others once you get the picture figured out.

Comment: Also, once you fix the photo problem, click "reopen". A few other people should follow along and this will reopen the question.

Comment: @DoxyLover  I don't see "reopen" anywhere.

Comment: @HotLicks - It should be at the bottom of the post, just below the "cast-iron" and "antique" tags.  Several options in the next line - share, edit, follow, reopen, and flag.

Comment: @Mark I guess I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @HotLicks - That may be.  You've got two votes now, it shouldn't take long to get another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Combination Plane, probably from the 19th century.

It combines all or some of the tool functions offered by *"a skewed cutter plow, dado, filletster and match plane".*

If it's a Stanley brand, the brand would be readable on the side. If not, it could be one of many imitations. Perhaps it's number "45", types 1 to 4. Later models have more adjustment screws.

[image]

> The “combination plane” was developed to create a woodworking tool that would perform multiple functions and free a workman from having to own a large number of individual planes.  Over a 50-year time span in the second half of the 19th century numerous inventors patented and produced a broad array of combination planes.

Ref: eaiainfo.org

There are several patents of this tool.

[image]

Images:

- http://www.oldtooluser.com/typestudy/stanno45combplanetypestudy.htm
- https://eaiainfo.org/there-is-a-stanley-no-145/

Comment: Thank you very much!  Value??

Comment: @billd. depends on the features (how many adjustments possible) and the accessories not depicted, if any. On ebay these vintage tools are around $80-$200. If it doesn't function because the screws have seized then its only ornamental, so less value. Where did you find it?

Comment: Got it at a local garage sale in Des Moines.  Thanks again!

Comment: @billd. ok well have fun with it. Glad this was useful. Remember to mark off the answer you liked best. That's a separate action in addition to any upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [rebate (or rabbet) plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebate_plane). A quick search shows brand new ones which look very similar in design. The further away part is a basic manual plane and the nearest part an adjustable fence to guide where the planing happens. I have no idea who made this specific one however.